# how to make a field of a query in mysql to be an INT

Tags: mysql

I am doing this query:

```
select tblagenda.ValorServicio, ((tblcopago.bonos + tblcopago.copago) * tblagenda.ValorServicio / grupo.Total) as Copago, grupo.Total
    from tblcopago
    inner join tblagenda on (tblagenda.CodigoOrden=tblcopago.CodigoOrden)
    join (select sum(ValorServicio) as Total, CodigoOrden from tblagenda group by CodigoOrden) grupo on grupo.CodigoOrden = tblagenda.CodigoOrden
```

I want the Copago field to be an INT

Comment: Just guessing: ROUND()? FLOOR()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to round the result:

```
 SELECT ROUND((tblcopago.bonos + tblcopago.copago) * tblagenda.ValorServicio / grupo.Total) as Copago
```

If you want to floor it (truncate to the lower int):

```
 SELECT FLOOR((tblcopago.bonos + tblcopago.copago) * tblagenda.ValorServicio / grupo.Total) as Copago
```

... And if you want the upper value (truncate + 1):

```
 SELECT CEIL((tblcopago.bonos + tblcopago.copago) * tblagenda.ValorServicio / grupo.Total) as Copago
```

See [MYSQL Mathematical Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html)